# AFNetworking migration from 1.x to 3.x

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am doing the migration of AFNetworking library from 1.x to 3.x for my project.

As per my understanding the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to be replaced with `AFHTTPSessionManager`.
What is the replacement for the method `cancel` and property `isCancelled`,`isReady`, `request` and `response` that are present in the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` class.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In** **AFHTTPRequestOperationManager**

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

**In** **AFHTTPRequestOperation**

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/resources/123.json"];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```